# Where to put website name in asp.net MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an asp.net MVC app, where is a good place to store the name (string) of a website so it is accessible through out the site as a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the name going to change depending on some sort of context?

If not, keep it as simple as possible. Put it in your config file or create a constant that you can access easily.

Start with the simplest possible solution and iterate to a more complex one if it is needed.

Comment: That will work.  Do you have any idea why this isn't available in vs.net 2015?

Comment: You mean a specific (global) variable for the site name? There has never been something like that in asp.net to my knowledge. The usual way is to create a config value or a string constant.

Comment: No - I mean the ability to add resource files.

Comment: asp.net 5 is still under active development and they are doing a lot of things different. Maybe support isn't added yet. I wouldn't use it for production purposes yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your resources file. This is a good place to store strings as a rule as it will facilitate localisation later. http://www.devcurry.com/2013/02/aspnet-mvc-using-resource-files-to.html?m=1

Comment: I'm guessing resource fies are not already in the project.  Do you know how to add one of these for an asp.net 5 (vs.net 2015) project?  I don't see resource files as something that can be added.

Comment: @4thSpace In VS(2013 anyhow) they are under General > Resources in the Add Item dialog

Comment: Right but I don't see this in vs.net 2015.

Comment: What about Project menu > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_GlobalResources, then the right click context menu off that folder?

Comment: Still no difference.  Since this isn't an option in vs.net 2015, where else can this string go?